# How to specify specific source for a certain pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, twilio

Although I believe this is harmless, warnings quite irk me. So I'm using a very specific version of **TwilioChatClient** together with **TwilioClient**. These two specific versions are what Twilio have been using in their sample projects.

Anyways, the warning when installing / updating pods:

> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.9)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.9/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.9/TwilioChatClient.podspec
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.8)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.8/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.8/TwilioChatClient.podspec
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.7)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.7/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.7/TwilioChatClient.podspec
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.6)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.6/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.6/TwilioChatClient.podspec
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.5)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.5/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.5/TwilioChatClient.podspec
>
> [!] Found multiple specifications for `TwilioChatClient (1.0.4)`:
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/7/d/e/TwilioChatClient/1.0.4/TwilioChatClient.podspec.json
>   - /Users/XXX/.cocoapods/repos/twilio/TwilioChatClient/1.0.4/TwilioChatClient.podspec

My podfile:

```
project 'Proj/Proj.xcodeproj'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'

platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

  target 'Proj' do

    pod 'TwilioClient', '~>1.2'     # Twilio Call Framework
    pod 'TwilioChatClient', '1.0.4' # Twilio Chat Framework


    target 'MobileMedTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end

  end

  target 'ProjUITests' do

  end
```

I think specifying two kinds of sources (which are both necessary) causes these warnings. Is there a way to put the specific source right beside the pod?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, your problem comes from the fact that you have added the twilio repo to your pod source with this line :

```
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
```

So when you type `pod repo`, you obtain something like :

```
master
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
- Path: /Users/cyrille/.cocoapods/repos/master

twilio
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs
- Path: /Users/cyrille/.cocoapods/repos/twilio
```

And when you execute `pod install`, cocoa pods can find a version of this lib both in master's cocoapods repo and in twilio's one... which make the warning.

To remove this warning, remove this line from your Podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
```

In a terminal execute the following commands :

```
pod repo remove twilio
```

and then :

```
pod update
```

You should get the following with no more warnings :

```
Analyzing dependencies
Removing TwilioClient
Downloading dependencies
Installing TwilioChatClient 2.2.0 (was 1.0.4)
Installing TwilioSDK (1.2.9)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

Comment: +1 for effort, but I believe I only need the very specific versions specific in my podfile. I don't know with Twilio team, I think their repo and documentation about versioning is not so organized.

Comment: Okay, now this works. This is the answer but I'm giving the points to Khawar, cause I think his podfile compelled me to update too the codes lol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems fair :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

First, You need SDK also.I installed pod on my project now. It works fine. Look up this link

http://cocoapods.org/?q=Twilio

**Pod Code**

```
project 'Proj/Proj.xcodeproj'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'

platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

  target 'Proj' do

    pod 'TwilioSDK', '1.2.9'
    pod 'TwilioChatClient'


    target 'MobileMedTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end

  end

  target 'ProjUITests' do

  end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe I had to combine cdescours' answer with yours. Will award the bounty to you after 9 hours, since this podfile pushed me to update the codes too.

Answer (score 2):

just wanted to give a bit of background on the warnings you saw here.  We use a separate cocoapods repository during beta testing (https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs) but began publishing to the global cocoapods repository soon after GA when 1.x was released.

We did not stop publishing to our existing cocoapod-specs repository for the rest of the 1.x releases because it would have been a breaking change to existing customers using the beta source line who wished to upgrade if they did not also have the global cocoapods repository declared.  This is what cocoapods is warning about, that the same pod with a same version is defined in two places.  The podspecs are identical, so this will not cause issues when using any of the versions of the SDK for which this warning shows up.

As of 2.x, we have been publishing chat only to the global repository so that is why the warnings stop with the 1.x series of releases.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't want to update to other versions of the frameworks used in the sample projects of Twilio. But after the guys posted their answers in this question, I've managed to update the frameworks and did some little updates on the codes too. That solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

   use_frameworks!

   platform :ios, '10.0' # (or whatever version you want)

   target 'Project Name' do

   pod 'TwilioSDK', '1.2.9'
   pod 'TwilioChatClient'

 post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a certain one pod? The `:source` property maybe it's just what you're looking for.

```
target 'Runner' do

  pod 'Masonry', :source => 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'  ## is the `:source` what u want ???
  pod 'openssl', :path => 'pods/openssl'
  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',:tag => '5.7.0'

end
```